# how to connect to local db from a virtual ubuntu server?

Tags: mysql, ubuntu-11.04

i have a virtual  ubuntu server running in windows 7 pro using VMware Player.
i have to connect to a mysql database which is there in windows7 (local) from the ubuntu server.
when i try connect to the database which is present in the windows7 from ubuntu server i get error saing Host ' the windows7-PC ' is not allowed to connect to this MySql server.

jdbc:mysql://mywindows7_IP:3306/mysql

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've to add the permission to connect from another IP to the username you're using. You can add an entry to `mysql.user` table duplicating the user you're using and changing the `Host` column to allow the IP address of your Ubuntu, or change the existing `Host` entry with `%`, which actually allows to connect from everywhere.

There is also an `Host` field in the `db` table, so in case you've restricted the access of that username to a particular DB, then you've to fix also `mysql.db` table.

After those changes, do a `FLUSH PRIVILEGES`, so MySQL can pick them up.